# Converting *.asc to *.shp without using ArcGIS for Desktop or QGIS?

Tags: shapefile, c#, convert, ascii

I am trying to perform file conversion programmatically, using C#.

I have read the [ESRI Shapefile Technical Description (An ESRI White Paper—July 1998)](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf).

I cannot calculate records for *.shp file from *.asc file.

Comment: I think you'll get a better answer if you add a little more detail to your question.  First, not all asc files are the same.  Can you show a sample including the header? Secondly, are you trying to convert it to a point dataset and third, when you say you cannot calculate the records, can you be more specific as to the problem you are having (e.g. is it a coding issue, a problem understanding the shapefile format or understanding the asc format)?

Comment: have a look at ogr2ogr (open source) http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: The shapefile specification is much more complete for .shp and .shx than .dbf -- i found coding the dBase component much more difficult.  You'll need to provide code and a detailed description of your problem (including why you need to reinvent this wheel) before we'll be able to provide much assistance.

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel which of course is good to do every now and then, you may want to have a look at dot spatial library. At least it is using your language.